# Deploying a springboot app with Ehcache on Openshift

Tags: spring-boot, caching, openshift

I have a springboot application which uses Ehcache for cache implementation. If I run the app locally, the caching works i.e. Ehcache registration, formation of cacheable methods etc. Now I have to deploy the application on openshift. I built the app into a docker image and ran that docker image on openshift. What I found is that caching is not working on Openshift. I cannot see log showing cache registration, instead I get following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'getRestrictedAddress' for Builder[public java.util.ArrayList com.optum.kafka.services.CodeListService.getRestrictedAddress()] caches=[getRestrictedAddress] | key=''getRestrictedAddressKey'' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'.

Here `getRestrictedAddress` is the name of cache that caches the result of a method that pulls data from database.

I have done following steps to enable caching locally:

1. add ehcache dependency to the pom
2. add a simple ehcache xml file and its classpath in application.properties
3. add @Cacheable notation above methods that need to be cached
4. add @EnableCaching in the cache config file

Can anyone help me on how to enable this caching on Openshift platform?Do I need any other configuration to add in the application?

Comment: What storage option are you using for ehcache? Also, are you running your container as root or as default openshift user?

Comment: Right now I am using heap and off heap resource for storage.The container is being run as a new user on openshift with some rights . Hope this answers your question!

Comment: This looks like you are having problems creating the cache. Maybe there is a permission issue and ehcache cannot write data to disk.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs but It was a mistake from my side. I did not configure this property 'spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml' properly in the config-map on open shift.

Comment: There is no need of extra configurations to be added on open shift or in the app to enable caching on open shift.